# Inserting array of struct into linked list

Tags: arrays, c, struct, linked-list

My linked lists exercise demands I make an array of struct, containing a name of person (Defined as a 4 character name) and the distance of that person from me.

After creating 3 array elements I then put each person and his distance into a linked list.

I've made the array and successfully printed it as is, but having trouble making the list.

My code is as follows, would very much appreciate a solution to get the code up and running.

```
    typedef struct Node
{
    int dist;
    char name[4];
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

void main()
{
    int i;
    Node arr[3];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("Enter name: \n");
    scanf("%s", arr[i].name);

    printf("Enter distance: \n");
    scanf("%d", &arr[i].dist);
}
printf("Basic printing of the ARRAY:");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("Distance of %s is: %d\n", arr[i].name, arr[i].dist);
}

printf("\n\n\n");
Node* head;
Node* tail;
head = tail = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
tail = malloc(sizeof(Node));
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
    
        head->dist = arr[i].dist;
        head->name[4] = arr[i].name;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tail = tail->next;
        tail->next = NULL;
        tail->dist = arr[i].dist;
        tail->name[4] = arr[i].name;
    }
}
Node* temp;
temp = head;
printf("Now we print the list\n");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("Distance of %s is: %d\n", temp->name, temp->dist);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a fix.
When inputting the name into the list the right thing to use is strcpy.

```
right way:
strcpy(tail->name, arr[i].name)

wrong way (what I used):
tail->name[4]=arr[i].name;
```